# Initializing "hidden" tooltips on page-load

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap

Greetings everyone :)

My question pertains to the bootstrap tooltips. I have a bunch of tooltips within my page (5 to be exact).

The tooltips look (more or less) like this:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="{{'calculation.ttSD' | translate}}"></span>
```

I initialize them at the very top of the page (right after the ) with the classic:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

Most tooltips are initialized without any problems, however 2 are not working properly. There are some parts of the page that are hidden as the page loads and revealed depending upon what the user has entered.

Example:

```
<tr ng-if="condition == 'true'">
<label data-translate="the.text.to.put.in.the.label"/>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" tittle="someText">
```

...

These tooltips are not getting initialized properly at the beginning. As a quick fix i just copied the above javascript and placed it right after the tooltips, which works. Except that kills the DRY principle since the same exact js comes up 3-4 times within the page.

What is a better way (if there is a way at all) of initializing all bootstrap tooltips, regardless if hidden or not?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`ng-if` prevents DOM Element from being rendered. Hence the initialization in `document.ready` will not take effect on your `ng-if` false elements

Instead you can use `ng-show/ ng-hide` as they only changes display css-poperty

modified your example to `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`

```
<tr ng-show="condition == 'true'">
<label data-translate="the.text.to.put.in.the.label"/>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" tittle="someText">
```

hope it helps

Comment: `ng-if` prevents them from being attached to the DOM, subsequently they will not be rendered.